# How to properly refresh a stale entity from a database?

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

In my web application I often need to keep entities read from the database  over the span of a single request and refresh them later in another request. Currently I have a helper method

```
protected <T> T refresh(T t) {
    if (!entityManager.contains(t)) {
        t = merge(t);
        entityManager.refresh(t);
    }
    return t;
}
```

Each method them refreshes the entity it's working on before anything else. If the entity has already been refreshed, nothing happens.

This worked nicely, until later I realized that this solution has a significant problem: **The call to `merge` fails if the entity has been concurrently modified in the database.** Obviously `merge` can't "know" that the content of `t` will be replaced anyway by the immediate call to `refresh`.

What would be the proper solution to this problem? So far I have these ideas, none of which feels completely satisfactory:

1. Instead of calling `merge` and `refresh`, get the ID of the entity and call

   ```
   t = find(theClassOfT, t.getId());
   ```

   This would solve the problem, I'd get a fully fresh entity, but it has a major drawback: I need to know the class of `T` and it's ID. Getting the ID can be accomplished by a having a top super-interface for all my entities, but getting the class is problematic (since a JPA implementation may subclass the entities, I'm afraid that calling `t.getClass()` could return some implementation specific subclass of `T`).
2. Keep only IDs in the long term and read entities fresh during each request. This seem more correct from the design point of view (stale entities carry invalid information anyway), but again requires to have the class of `T` at hand.

**Update:** The reason I'm keeping the entities across the requests is merely for convenience. I specifically don't need to ensure that the entity isn't modified during that time - I refresh it at the next request anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your #1 should work.

`object.getClass()` should work for the class, for the Id you can use `emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(object)`.

Also not you can pass a properties `Map` to the `find()` operation, and can include the refresh query hint ("eclipselink.refresh"="true" or ["javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH"](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjjj.html#gkjds)), this can avoid potential 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are describing [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

One approach is to lock the entity until a client will commit the changes - this will lower tour app's throughput.

Or use optimistic locking - you can hope that the object will not change, place the identifier of version in the entity. Once the objects is being saved, the number is checked against current state in DB and if it does not match, because another client changed the entity, this concurrent update just fail. Your application must be able to solve the state once concurrent modifications happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh an entity from the database you're probably doing something wrong.

Your entities should not live any longer than required. Your JPA provider should handle caching, so recalling the same query and retrieving the same entity again shouldn't be much of a fuss. So, store your entity in @RequestScoped, @ConversationScoped and similar scopes.

On the other hand, if you do need the entity for a longer period of time, you should look into locking. As the previous poster explained, you can either do:

- **pessimistic locking**, where you LOCK entity and prevent anybody else from updating it before  you commit
- **optimistic locking**, where you expect the entity not to be updated, but `save()` may fail somebody has

Read more about locking and JPA for example here: http://city81.blogspot.com/2011/03/pessimistic-and-optimistic-locking-in.html